# ajax request denied in spring security , Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

hi In my grails application I am using spring security

in one of my view page (GSP)
i am making an ajax call to an action in one of the controller
but the request is denied and i end up in the "ajaxDenied()' action in Login controller

here is my ajax call

```
function setTagged(id)
{
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "./email/setTagged",
        type:"post",
//      data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList), option:option, id:id}
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data); //<-----this logs the data in browser's console
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            alert(xhr.responseText); //<----when no data alert the err msg
        }
    });
    alert("here 1");
}
```

here is my config.groovy part where spring security plugin allows which pages to be 
accesible

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.spi.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.spi.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.spi.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],

    '/login/*':                       ['permitAll'],
    '/home/*':                       ['permitAll'],
    '/logout/*':                      ['permitAll'],

    '/message/*':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/ticket/*':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/email/*':                       ['permitAll'],
    '/role/*':                        ['permitAll'],
    '/user/*':                        ['permitAll'],


    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']]
```

any suggestion how can i call any action from my own controllers via an ajax call ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the version of your spring-security plugin ?

I don't know if it is the problem, but the version 2.0 is more aggressively secure by default and use the pessimistic lockdown ([What's New](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/newInV2.html) and [Pessimistic Lockdown](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#requestMappings)).

Did you define the @secured annotation for your action ?

Comment: well yes I am using version 2.0 , any ways I can still play with Ajax ??

Comment: Of course you can! If it is a problem of annotation(s), you just need to add this import in your controller:

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])

class YourController {
...
}

Comment: You can find more information about the annotations with this
[link](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations)