# Grails Spring Security Plugin setting up anonymous access with config type annotation

Tags: grails, spring-security

According to the docs, when setting up controllers to be accessible by anybody, just leave then not annoatated by @Secured

In my case if its not annotated, my requests always ends up being denied/403.

```
def show(User userInstance) {
    searchTargetUser()
}
```

Its worth noting that, its working as expected when annotated with @Secured.

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_OWNER'])
def show(User userInstance) {
    searchTargetUser()
}
```

How do you allow a method to be accessible anonymously?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Your answer is here (in the comments of the first reply): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166828/ajax-request-denied-in-spring-security-grails/23174284#23174284

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer.
To be able to allow anonymous access to a controller or controller method you just add:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']) 
def method(){
}
```

or:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']) 
class SomethingController{
}
```

Comment: Yes, @froi could you please show us where did you find it?

Comment: You can take a look at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/requestMappings.html or http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/ for explanations.